# Packing event arguments in a class, why?

Tags: c#, .net, events

Most .NET stock events are have this signature:

```
delegate void SomethingSomething(SomethingEventArgs e);
event SomethingSomething OnSomethingSomething;
```

and

```
class SomethingEventArgs
{
    public string Name;
    public int Index;
    public double Groar;
}
```

Why is that better (obviously is, otherwise anyone would choose to do) than:

```
delegate void SomethingSomething(string Name, int Index, double Groar);
event SomethingSomething OnSomethingSomething;
```

since you don't have to pack your parameters to an object, and without initializers (.NET 2.0) it was kind of typing exercise.

One reason that comes to mind is that you can return your values simpler when having them packed in an object - ie. handler can modify a member of the object.  However, with multicast events, that can't always be good anyway.

So, why?

Comment: 15 points doesn't do much. Just wondering if you wanted me (or someone else) to elaborate the answer.

Comment: Nono, I embraced the right way, and I gathered plenty of reasons to do it, apart from seeing that I have multiple changes if I want to add something to the event argument list.  Thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Read about [Open/Closed principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416500/understanding-the-open-closed-principle).

By using a class, all inherited classes can introduce extra functionality without having to change the delegate signature. They can simply introduce a new event class (`ExtendedEventArgs`) which inherits yours (`SomeEventArgs`).

Comment: This is the only truly correct answer here, in real-world practice.

Answer (score 15):

The main reason is that it is more maintainable. If you pass an objects and any of the properties change, you only have to modify that. If you pass variables, that is a lot more work. So, the code gets more maintainable and more readable this way.

A quote from Microsoft's [Code Complete](http://books.google.nl/books?id=3JfE7TGUwvgC&pg=PT284&lpg=PT284&dq=seven%20is%20a%20magic%20number%20for%20people%27s%20comprehension&source=bl&ots=RQsV1H4OgH&sig=InXOAo3uOlmVfFj4ATjYqJtvJhE&hl=nl&ei=VqjPTp6dCo2gOq272LsD&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=seven%20is%20a%20magic%20number%20for%20people%27s%20comprehension&f=false):

> Limit the number of a routine’s parameters to about seven. Seven is a
>   magic number for people’s comprehension. Psychological research has
>   found that people generally cannot keep track of more than about seven
>   chunks of information at once (Miller 1956). This discovery has been
>   applied to an enormous number of disciplines, and it seems safe to
>   conjecture that most people can’t keep track of more than about seven
>   routine parameters at once.
>
> In practice, how much you can limit the
>   number of parameters depends on how your language handles complex data
>   types. If you program in a modern language that supports structured
>   data, you can pass a composite data type containing 13 fields and
>   think of it as one mental “chunk” of data. If you program in a more
>   primitive language, you might need to pass all 13 fields individually,
>
> If you find yourself consistently passing more than a few arguments,
>   the coupling among your routines is too tight. Design the routine or
>   group of routines to reduce the coupling. 1f you are passing the same
>   data to many different routines, group the routines into a class and
>   treat the frequently used data as class data.

[Quoted text from the original post's  image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLpDB.png)

Comment: Doesn't the same problem apply but just on a different location? The object construction and interpretation?

Comment: Yes, I see that - I have: delegate signature, FireXXX signature, subscriber signatures...  Well - will think of that in the future...

Comment: As per my answer, it also means you can add more information to your event without breaking any existing subscribers.

Comment: Your added quotation (which I agree with) has got nothing to do with your first point (which I don't agree with as indicated in my previous comment).

Comment: Seven arguments seems to be awful lot in object oriented languages.

Comment: @jgauffin: I agree...did I say something else? The number 7 is just used in the quote and is not a number that is just made up by someone. The quote also says that the limit of the number of parameters is language dependent. So...what do you want to say with your comment?

Comment: Being quite aggressive, aren't we?

Comment: Not at all, I just don't not understand why you posted that comment.

Comment: BTW, why quote McConnell as a bitmap?

Comment: I could not find an option to get it as text and did not want to type it in manually. But, if you have the text, feel free to edit my post.

Comment: I translated the text with OneNote. It'll show once reviewed.

Answer (score 11):

The reason for this is to avoid breaking changes. For example, your class may wish to include further information with it's event, however every thing which used that event would break, as the delegate no longer matched. By having a strict delegate, your event can encapsulate more information in the future without affecting any subscribers.

Edit: As per the comments I'll expand on how this affects the reduction of breaking changes.

If we wished to add further information to our raised event, by using a single class derived from `EventArgs` new properties/methods can be added. This will mean any existing subscribers to the event will require no change, as the addition of these properties does not affect them. The only required change would be where these properties are set/used, e.g. where the event is raised.

Comment: As in [Baszz's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8270545/590790), _"doesn't the same problem apply but just on a different location? The object construction and interpretation?"_

Comment: @StevenJeuris If I added further properties to our derived `EventArgs` class, only the instantiation of this class would be affected (most likely where the event is raised), any existing listeners would merely use the previously existing properties and ignore these new ones, eliminating any breaking changes.

Comment: Ah! True, that's an oversight of mine. Then it becomes a rather subjective discussion whether you prefer code to break when it changes conceptually or not. My opinion is, when I add an argument, I most likely add it for a reason and should probably review the code where it is used anyway. But I agree it can be an advantage, thanks for the feedback. Consider clarifying that in your answer, so I can remove the down vote. ;p

Comment: @StevenJeuris I've clarified it in my answer, and you're right, it's good to review the code using the event when possible, however for libraries being released for use by third-parties, this is unfortunately not possible.

Answer (score 9):

The benefit is the pattern; and having a pattern gives both consistency and the the ability to use other APIs across multiple event types:

- The [`EventHandler<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler.aspx) delegate type (you don't need to define your own delegate type).
- The Reactive Extensions (Rx) have conversion of an event into an `IObservable<T>` allowing use of LINQ on event sources with [`Observable.FromEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.fromevent%28VS.103%29.aspx).

---

Also you've got the signatures wrong:

- The delegate takes *two* arguments: `object source` and `SomethingEventArgs`
- The `SomethingEventArgs` type inherits [`EventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventargs.aspx).

Thus your code should be, to be an exemplar of the pattern:

At namespace scope:

```
public class SomethingEventArgs : EventArgs {
    public string Name;
    public int Index;
    public double Groar;
}

public delegate void SomethingSomething(object source, SomethingEventArgs e);
```

and in the type exposing the type

```
public event SomethingSomething OnSomethingSomething;
```

(An event could also be `internal`.)

Comment: @DanielMošmondor the "simplification" removes the pattern and the point.

Comment: how, when the point is in packing the event arguments, not in having the class inherit some common class nor how to send the ORIGINATOR of the event?  POINT: packing parameters.

Comment: Anyway, if you think that you understood the point better, feel free to edit the question :)

Comment: @DanielMošmondor I've expanded the correction here, I don't want to change the question because I think your choice to simplify tells us about why you are asking the question.

Answer (score 6):

As others have pointed out, there are maintainability and concistency reasons for this. The EventArgs approach also makes it possible for the event handler to *modify* the EventArgs.

One reason for modifying the EventArgs is errorhandling. An exception caught somewhere on a background thread is communicated to the client as an event. The client can set a flag in the EventArgs to indicate the exception was handled an shouldn't be rethrown on the background thread.

Another example is the `ObjectDataSource` class that lets the client supply an object instance when one is required. This is done by subscribing to the `ObjectDataSource.ObjectCreating` event and supplying the object instance by setting a member of the EventArgs.

Answer (score 3):

Using a class allows the event's subscribers to effect the outcome.

When you pass an instance of a class as a parameter to a method, it is passed by reference.  This allows the object instance to change during the method call.  Those changed values can then be read by the caller after the event is raised.

For instance:

Look at the [FormClosingEventHandler Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventhandler.aspx) (in Windows Forms).

This delegate uses a parameter of type [FormClosingEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs.aspx).

If a subscriber to an event using this delegate sets the [Cancel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs.cancel.aspx) property (inherited by [CancelEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs.aspx)) to true, then the form is not closed.

In addition, these answers are also correct:

1. [jgauffin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8270605/213474)
2. [Baszz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8270545/213474)

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, the reason **why** this pattern is so common (as you have asked) is because **Microsoft has specifically prescribed** so when they developed the **[Event Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817669.aspx)** (yes they coined this term, too).  I don't necessarily think this is better or worse than coming up with your own delegate signatures, but following a well-known convention can have its advantages.

Per Microsoft:

> - The return type is Void.
> - The first parameter is named sender and is of type Object. This is the object that raised the event.
> - The second parameter is named e and is of type EventArgs or a derived class of EventArgs. This is the event-specific data.
> - The method takes exactly two parameters.

To get more at the point of your question, though, I think the rationale for using EventArgs is twofold:

1. So that **classes that inherit from your class** can still raise the event, with a derived EventArgs class.
2. So that **classes that handle your event** can use common event handlers to handle several types of events, even if different events use different EventArgs.  Or, if you change the event down the road, any classes that already handle the event don't need to change their code because the handlers will still be compatible with the new event.

For further reading, see more info from Microsoft:

1. More info about how to design events: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229011.aspx
2. A detailed how-to on using this pattern: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w369ty8x.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In order to follow the [.net standards](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w369ty8x%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), the recommanded way to create an event is:

1. Create a class that inherits from `EventArgs`
2. Use the `EventHandler<T>` generic delegate

As doing so reduces the amount of work required to subsequently change the number and types of values sent to event subscribers.

Example:

```
public event EventHandler<SometingEventArgs> SomethingEvent;

class SomethingEventArgs 
{     
      public string Name;    
      public int Index;     
      public double Groar; 
}
```

Comment: If Mircosoft recommands to use EventHandler<T> it is for the maintainability and a better code reading

Comment: Yes, but why? Add _"Why is this the recommended way?"_ underneath your answer, and you get the same question than the OP, although formulated better.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the backward-compatibility convention that others have already mentioned, the EventArgs class enables more control over how the parameters are contiguously accessed as they are passed to more than one object.

This control can be used to make certain values immutable, so that if an event is sent to 3 different subscribers you can guarantee it's not tampered with.

At the same time you can offer multiple [out] values, and you don't have to juggle return values or [ref] parameters, which significantly complicates the multicasting process.  It also ensures that any validation logic occurs in the EventArgs subclass, NOT in the class that fires the events.