# Calling methods with different parameters using a map instead of switch/if else

Tags: c#, dictionary, if-statement, switch-statement

I am working a c# method which calls different methods based on some conditions and I am wondering if I can do this without switch or if else statements.
Below is the code I have

```
if (msg== atype)
{
    _aHandler.HandleAType(msg, TopicType.A);
}
else if (msg== btype)
{
    _
    _btype.HandleBType(msg, TopicType.B);
}
else if (msg== ctype)
{
    _cHandler.HandleC(msg);
}
else if (msg== dtype)
{
    _dHandler.HandleDType(msg);
}

else
    _logger.Error($"No matching type found for {msg}");
```

Please note that I have different methods with different types of parameters in each condition.

**Is there a better way I can do this without switch/if-else ?**

Comment: `_aHandler` , `_cHandler` are objects of classes inherited from the same base class or interface?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya No they are not. each condition may or may not have methods from same base class or different

Comment: looks very similar to another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416500/understanding-the-open-closed-principle

Comment: No, there is not a better way. You could throw a `#region` around it if it's really bothering you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean something like this:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, Action>
{
    {atype, () => _aHandler.HandleAType(atype, TopicType.A)},
    {btype, () => _btype.HandleBType(btype, TopicType.B)},
    {ctype, () => _cHandler.HandleC(ctype)},
    {dtype, () => _dHandler.HandleDType(dtype)}
};

//Call it
dic[msg]();
```

Comment: I can't see how this improves on the readability or maintainability of OP's original version.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Not really no, but he specifically asked for an implementation _"using a map instead of switch/if else"_ so I assume it is for educational purposes.

Comment: OK, fair enough.

Comment: Maintenance is obviously a subjective topic, what Magnus has is far better as far as cyclomatic complexity is concerned.